# How do I perform a non-blocking fopen on a named pipe (mkfifo)?

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, blocking, fifo

If I have a program which creates and attempts to open a named pipe using mkfifo, how can I open a pipe for reading or writing without blocking?

Specifically, I'm writing a C program which can be run with or without a gui (written in Java).

In the C program, I successfully create the named pipes using mkfifo, however when I do

```
FILE* in = fopen(PIPE_IN, "r"); /* Where PIPE_IN is the filename*/
```

fopen doesn't return until the GUI opens that pipe for writing. What I wish to do is have that pipe ready to be read once (if) the GUI decides to write to it - I'll be putting the file descriptor in a select() call. It's reasonable to expect that the java GUI may never actually be started, so I cannot rely on it to open the other end of the pipe at any specific point or even at all.

I will also have a second pipe open for writing, and I assume I will have the same problem. Further, I can't set O_NONBLOCK on an output pipe that has no reader.

Any suggestions?

(This is running on a linux system)

Comment: Do you need to open the output pipe prior to select() firing on the input pipe?

Comment: @tinkertim - I suppose technically not - I had set them both up in a setup function, but I could just set up the output pipe first and then call select, why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could `open()` your pipe `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK`, and if you want the C stream, you can get it with `fdopen()`. However, there might be a problem with the `select()` - AFAIK, a pipe fd open for reading that has no writer is always prepared for reading, and `read()` returns 0, so the `select()` would fire indefinitely.

A kludgy way of overcoming this would be to open the pipe `O_RDWR`; that is, have at least one writer (your C++ program). Which would solve your problem anyway.

Comment: I'll give that a shot for the reader - but I can't set O_NONBLOCK on an output pipe...

Comment: The POSIX standard says (of select()): "A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully."  (POSIX.1:2008).

Comment: Opening the pipe O_RDWR would lead to deadlock when the program reads (or writes) - unless there is actually another process also with the pipe open.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - But could I open it RDWR and just poll it to see when another process actually has written to it? That shouldn't cause deadlocks, right?

Comment: Yes, and this should block in select(). No such solutions for the writing end of a pipe, probably the best thing you could do is open the writing end after you've received some prompt from the Java program

Comment: @jpalecek Yeah, I realized that's what I had to do last night after thinking about why tinkertim asked about the order in the comment to the original question.