# Lua Non blocking read acces on empty FIFO

Tags: lua

I am writing a little lua script that read data from a FIFO.for this I use the classical:

```
f=assert(io.open("/tmp/myfifo")
f:read()
```

When the fifo is empty/not feeded, my script block. Is there a way to avoid this ?.

Comment: Strange, here it simply returns `nil` when there's nothing left in the fifo.

Comment: It seems that there is blocking read access and non blocking read access on fifo on Linux. The fifo that my script try to read is generated by mpd. If I use cat on the empty fifo, the cat command block until there is data in the fifo.

Comment: Ah, well Now I see. It's the io.open that blocks, not the reading.

Comment: Hum not really, I have checked if I just use f=io.open("/tmp/myfifo"); f:close the script doesn't block

Comment: I think its simply impossible with the basic Lua functions I tried  [this post about fopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580013/how-do-i-perform-a-non-blocking-fopen-on-a-named-pipe-mkfifo) setting the mode r+ did the io.open unblocking, but made the read blocking :p

Comment: Ok so, is there a solution with something like threads? one thread which launch read action and one thread which check for timeout and end the other thread. I tried coroutine but it doesn't seem to be paralell execution..

Answer (score 3):

There is no straight forward Lua-only method I guess. With luajit http://luajit.org/ (which provides ffi) it is possible:

```
 local ffi = require'ffi'

 --- The libc functions used by this process.
 ffi.cdef[[
      int open(const char* pathname, int flags);
      int close(int fd);
      int read(int fd, void* buf, size_t count);
 ]]   
 local O_NONBLOCK = 2048
 local chunk_size = 4096
 local buffer = ffi.new('uint8_t[?]',chunk_size)
 local fd = ffi.C.open('mypipe',O_NONBLOCK)     
 local nbytes = ffi.C.read(fd,buffer,chunksize)
 -- .. process data
```

Comment: With [Tarantool](https://Tarantool.io) which provides the built in [fio.open()](https://Tarantool.io/en/doc/2.1/reference/reference_lua/fio/#fio-open) there's `O_NONBLOCK` flag.