# How to get structured data from a named pipe and write it into a qtableview in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, pipe

```
struct my_structure {
    char name[15]; /*thread name*/
    int pid; /* pid of the thread */
    int ppid; /* parent pid of the thread */
};

struct my_structure m1[]={{"skier",12,14},{"skier1",13,14}};
```

I want to display the contents of these these structure instances in a table in Qt using `QTableView`. so want to pass this structured data to my Qt program through a named pipe/fifo.

Please guide me how to pass this structured data in my Qt program through named pipe/fifo and how to read the contents of the structure from the fifo so that i could display them in a `QTableView`. also suggest me the code for displaying the contents of the structure in a table.

Answer (score 0):

use [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)("/path/to/named-pipe",....) & then [fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)/[fwrite](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) or

use [open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open)("/path/to/named-pipe",....) & then [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)/[write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

You can read/write the fifos in same manner as simple files.

For non-blocking IO, refer : [How do I perform a non-blocking fopen on a named pipe (mkfifo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580013/how-do-i-perform-a-non-blocking-fopen-on-a-named-pipe-mkfifo)