# How to stop fgets reading from FIFO file

Tags: c, linux, process, fifo

I have two processes, first reading from stdin and writing to FIFO file, second is waiting for message from FIFO file.

I am using this program structure:

```
while(run)
{
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp);
}
```

and when the sentinel (run) change to 0 to stop process, it didn't really stop because it stuck in `fgets()` function.
How can I solve it?

I want program to waits for the message when sentinel change to 0 then immediately stop the program.

Comment: The common way to do this is to use `select` to wait for input before calling `fgets`. To break out early, clear `run` and then send a signal to the process. The signal will interrupt `select`, it will go back to the top of the loop, see that `run` has cleared and will thus exit.

Comment: Can you tell how it will look  like in this particular case ??

Comment: Another option is to use a signal handler to clear `run`. If the handler is installed without `SA_RESTART` flag, its delivery will interrupt any blocking read/write syscalls in the same thread. Personally, I'd use low-level (unistd.h) I/O, nonblocking, and select(), though.

Comment: What would cause `run` to change?

Comment: i change run with the signal. Am i right that program return to to place where  signal appears ??

Comment: Have you added `volatile` in the declaration of `run`?

Comment: @sun qingyao You are the Man :) it works almost all now, in some cases it don't stop. But when i gave volatile it really helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think here your fifo is opened in **Blocking mode**, So in `fgets()` in read call if data is not available that call will be blocked till fifo has some new data.

SO to avoid this open FIFO in non blocking mode by using `O_NONBLOCK` in open call.

Read more here . http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node19.html

This way if no data is available fgets with return with error instead of stucking that call. In next while loop check,`run` will be 0 so it come out from this loop.

Comment: to open fifo i use fopen() function.  Can i set something like this in fopen ??

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580013/how-do-i-perform-a-non-blocking-fopen-on-a-named-pipe-mkfifo   Using open() open fifo and then using fdopen() convert file discriptor  to file pointer and then perform all file operation

Comment: i got this problem when i'm using fdopen: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: you may be doing something wrong. Post a new question with details of some code. so other people can help you